# Why does Powershell -replace change the type of an object

Tags: powershell

I'm a bit confused about some behavior I'm seeing.

The following code is designed to find and replace several strings in the registry.

```
$keys = @(gci -Path hkcu:\ -recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
foreach ($key in $keys)
{
    foreach ($vname in $key.GetValueNames())
    {
        $val = $key.GetValue($vname, $null, [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueOptions]::DoNotExpandEnvironmentNames)
        if ($val -like "c:\users\administrator*")
        {
            $nval = $val -replace "(?i:^(C:\\users\\Administrator))", "%USERPROFILE%"
            write-host "$key\$vname=$val -> $nval"
            ((Get-Item $Key.PSParentPath).OpenSubKey($Key.PSChildName, "True")).SetValue($vname, $nval, $key.GetValueKind($vname)) 
        }
    }
}
```

I continue to get the following error message when the registry value type is REG_MULTI_SZ. `Exception calling "SetValue" with "3" argument(s): "The type of the value object did not match the specified RegistryValueKind or the object could not be properly converted."`

If I comment out the -replace portion, i.e.:

```
    $nval = $val #-replace "(?i:^(C:\\users\\Administrator))", "%USERPROFILE%"
```

The registry keys are updated without errors (obviously with the same value they were).

So, something in the -replace operation is changing the data type. It appears to change in to type System.Object[].

The registryKey.SetValue method requires a string[] to set REG_MULTI_SZ.

**Why is it changing the type? And how do I work around this behavior?**

**UPDATE:**
Applying Option #1 in the answer did not work. `$nval` was still of type `System.Object[]` even after adding the cast. Applying option #3 did work.

Here is the final code that correctly searches and replaces a string found at the beginning of a string in the registry.

```
$keys = @(gci -Path hkcu:\ -recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
foreach ($key in $keys)
{
    foreach ($vname in $key.GetValueNames())
    {
        $val = $key.GetValue($vname, $null, [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueOptions]::DoNotExpandEnvironmentNames)
        if ($val -like "c:\users\administrator*")
        {
            if ($key.GetValueKind($vname) -eq [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind]::MultiString)
                { $nval = $val -replace "(?i:^(C:\\users\\Administrator))", "%USERPROFILE%" -as [string[]] }
            else
                { $nval = $val -replace "(?i:^(C:\\users\\Administrator))", "%USERPROFILE%" }

            write-host "$key\$vname=$val -> $nval"
            ((Get-Item $Key.PSParentPath).OpenSubKey($Key.PSChildName, "True")).SetValue($vname, $nval, $key.GetValueKind($vname)) 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most things in PowerShell that return multiple objects return them as an `[object[]]`; most likely because you could return any number of different objects, and because PowerShell wraps most objects in `[PSObject]` whether you know it or not.

So although you may start with a `[string[]]`, modifying it would result in an `[object[]]`.

When you need an array of a specific type, the simple way is to just cast it.

You have 3 options for casting it: cast the value of the assignment or cast the variable, or use the `-as` operator.

### Casting the value:

```
$nval = [string[]]($val -replace "(?i:^(C:\\users\\Administrator))", "%USERPROFILE%")
```

Now `$nval` will be a `[string[]]` unless you re-assign something else to it later.

### Casting the variable:

```
[string[]]$nval = $val -replace "(?i:^(C:\\users\\Administrator))", "%USERPROFILE%"
```

This works a little bit differently. Putting the cast on the variable in PowerShell applies that cast to all values assigned to it.

This is a good option when you know `$nval` always needs to be `[string[]]` and you don't want to cast it on every assignment.

### `-As` operator:

```
$nval = $val -replace "(?i:^(C:\\users\\Administrator))", "%USERPROFILE%" -as [string[]]
```

This is similar to casting the value; the difference is that it doesn't throw an exception if the cast is unsuccessful, it just returns `$null`.

---

To deal with the different registry kinds and the casts needed, I recommended a `switch` statement in the comments, but I came up with a better idea: just use a hashtable:

```
$kindToType = @{
    [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind]::MultiString = [string[]]
    [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind]::ExpandString = [string]
    [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind]::String = [string]
    [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind]::DWord = [int]
    # etc.
}
```

Then:

```
$nval = $val -replace "(?i:^(C:\\users\\Administrator))", "%USERPROFILE%" -as $kindToType[$key.GetValueKind($vname)]
```

This creates a lookup table where you can directly get a type from a registry kind.

Comment: Sorry I commented too soon. I still receive the error on the REG_MULTI_SZ, but now the REG_SZ and REG_EXPAND_SZ values are set to `System.Object[]` rather than the expected value of $nval. These other registry value types require just a string and not a string[]. I used your first method (cast the value). I did try casting the variable in different ways earlier, with the same results. I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: @Appleoddity I'm not fully following, but the if a value expects a string and you give it an array (even with just a single member), then you'll need to cast it to `[string]` (or just use `$myArray[0]`). When you see a literal `System.Object[]` it means that `.ToString()` was called (implicitly) on the array. You see this yourself at the prompt:  `@('Hello').ToString()`.

Comment: Thanks again. To clarify, if I send the "casted" array to the SetValue method when the registry value type expects a string, I will actually see `System.Object[]` in that value when viewed in regedit. I expect I'll fix this by using an extra if statement and checking the value and casting it if necessary. What you say makes sense. But, the original problem still stands, even if I cast the value I'm still getting the same error when trying to set a REG_MULTI_SZ value.

Comment: @Appleoddity it would be good if you edit your question to show the updated code with casts, and the errors you get there. Since you are trying to set 3 different kinds of values, it might be useful to use a `switch` statement on the RegistryKind and apply an appropriate cast depending on what it is.

Comment: I started to update the question, then realized I had placed the cast in the wrong place. I moved it to the right place (like in option #1 of your answer) and it still didn't work. `$nval` was still of type `System.Object[]` - strange. I'd like to know why. But, I was able to use option #3 with the `-as [string[]]` statement and it worked successfully. I will need to implement a `switch` or `if` statement to cast as necessary, like you stated - because it does break the other registry types. Thanks again.

Comment: @Appleoddity great glad it worked out. I updated the answer with a suggestion other than a `switch` statement

Comment: @Appleoddity: The only conceivable way in which option #1 can fail is if you forget to put `(...)` around the expression to cast to `[string[]]`; e.g., if you do `[string[]] 'foo', 'bar'` instead of `[string[]] ('foo', 'bar')`, you still get a `System.Object[]` array, because the cast applies to the _first_ element only  (due to operator precedence), whereas the `,` constructs a regular `System.Object[]` array.

Comment: I think that is exactly what I did. Not sure how I missed the parenthesis, but that makes sense. Thanks again for all the help! The method of using a hashtable for the kind to type conversion is genius. Or at least I think so. I was wondering if something like this was possible. I'll have to do some more research so I understand it better.

Comment: @Appleoddity a `[hashtable]` is just a collection of key/value pairs. Both the key and the value can be any object (but must be unique within the collection). The `[RegistryValueKind]` type is an enum, so those descriptive names all map to unique initegers. The values in this case are types, which are themselves objects, so it's a really simple mapping.

Comment: Thanks. It is the "values in this case are types" which is remarkable to me. I'm not sure why, but I didn't think this was possible. But very neat.

Comment: @Appleoddity yeah perhaps it's easier to see by just assigning a type directly to a variable: `$m = [math] ; $m::Sqrt(169)`. Yet another useful thing I learned from doing [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com). :)

Answer (score 2):

To complement [briantist's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48157409/45375) with a focused summary:

- If the LHS of a `-replace` expression is a *collection*<sup>[1]</sup>
  , the replacement is performed on *each of its elements*.
- The results are returned as a *regular PowerShell array*, which is of type `[System.Object[]]` - *irrespective of the specific type of the input collection*.
- To preserve the input collection type, you must use an explicit cast or call an appropriate constructor - see briantist's answer.

Example:

```
# Apply -replace to a LHS of type [System.Collections.ArrayList]
$result = ([System.Collections.ArrayList] ('one', 'two')) -replace 'o', '@'

> $result
@ne
tw@

> $result.GetType().FullName # inspect the result's type
System.Object[]
```

---

<sup>[1] Without having looked at the source code, it seems that "collection" in this sense refers to any type that implements interface `[System.Collections.IEnumerable]` that doesn't *also* implement `[System.Collections.IDictionary]`; for a given instance `$coll`, you can test as follows:

`$coll -is [System.Collections.IEnumerable] -and $coll -isnot [System.Collections.IDictionary]`.

Notably, this **excludes hashtable-like collections**, such as `[hashtable]` (literal syntax `@{ ... }`) and `[System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary]` (literal syntax `[ordered] @{ ... }`).</sup>